# Specific URL-Rewriting with Nginx using location,rewrite and alias

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, location

I am a beginner with Nginx and I've a question with a specific URL Rewriting.

I want "http://myserver.fr/context/[xxxxxxxxxxx]/synchronize.php" to redirect to /space/www/synchronize.php

And I want another URL type "http://myserver.php/context/[xxxxxxxx]" to redirect to /space/www/index.php

So I think the correct conf Nginx is :

```
   location /context/ {
            alias /space/www/;
            rewrite ^(.*).synchronize.php /synchronize.php last;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
     }
```

As I am a beginner in Nginx, can you tell me if my idea is logical or not? Thanks a lot.